# How to perform mousemove based on webelement instead of xy coordinates of getlocation in Selenium using robot class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseevent, mousemove

Problem Statement: How to perform mousemove based on webelement instead of xy coordinates of getlocation in Selenium using robot class?

Below snippet is often used to mousemove which moves mouse based on x-y co-ordinates

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.mouseMove(to_x, to_y);
```

But, Is there a way to **move mouse of robot class** based **on webelement without using getlocation?**

```
Example:
    webelement drag = driver.findelement(by_xpath('xpaht'))
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(drag); //Is there any way to do it like this in selenium java
```

I do not want to use movetoelement of actions class.

Selenium 3.141 / Java
Chromedriver 76 and FF browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use Locatable  class -

```
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));enter code here
int y = hoverItem.getCoordinates().getLocationOnScreen().getY();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+y+");");
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the snippet but I'm seeing exception as 'java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.Locatable'

Comment: Can you try this -
element =driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"))
 public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
        if (element instanceof Locatable) {
            return ((Locatable) element).getCoordinates();
        }

Comment: above solution also resulted with same exception.

Comment: getcoordinates will return x-y co-ords which might have dependency on y co-ordinate. Is there a way to avoid this dependency and robot.mousemove(toelement) directly.